# The GPIO External Interrupt doesn't work

Tags: interrupts, gpio-external-interrupt, stm32f10x

I have written this program for GPIO External Interrupt but it doesn't work. look at the program:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f10x.h"


/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

void GPIO_Configuration(void);
void EXTI_Configuration(void);
void NVIC_Configuration(void);


/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : main
* Description    : Main Programme
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
    GPIO_Configuration();
    NVIC_Configuration();
    EXTI_Configuration();


    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1)
    {

  }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name  : GPIO_Configuration
* Description    : Configure GPIO Pin
* Input          : None
* Output         : None
* Return         : None
* Attention      : None
*******************************************************************************/
void GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB , ENABLE);                        
/**
 *  LED1 -> PB0
 */                  
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* PB2-> Input */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

}

void EXTI_Configuration(void)
{

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE); 

  GPIO_EXTILineConfig(GPIO_PortSourceGPIOB, GPIO_PinSource2);
  EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line2);

    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line2;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
  EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);

}

void NVIC_Configuration(void)
{

  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI2_IRQn;   
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;      
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure); 
}

void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if ( EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line2) != RESET ) {
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line2);
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB , GPIO_Pin_0);
    }

}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *   where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif

/******************************************************************************************
      END FILE
******************************************************************************************/
```

and this my circuit:

[image]

I have even pulled-down the PB2 but doesn't work, again. the program correctly build and download (without any error or warning).

What's the problem? any idea?

Comment: Add a pull down resistor to the input pin, i.e. \$10k\Omega\$ between PB2 and ground. And please add a resistor for that LED, \$1k\Omega\$ is ok, if it turns on it will probably fry. Maybe your circuit does not work because you fried it already...

Comment: Moreover, your interrupt routine turns on the led but it's never turned off. The odds you burnt it are quite high I'd say.

Comment: @VladimirCravero As I said, I have already pulled-down it but... No, The LED is ok. yeah, I know but it doesn't work for one time even.

Comment: I read it, for me pull down means "I short circuited it to ground". The pull down resistor is needed anyway, as well as the led resistor, if you care about its lifetime. Can you also please try that your led turns properly on by setting the pin in software, just before the while(1)?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes, I tried it. it works nicely (I setted and resetted the led before infinit loop and that works).

Comment: My advice then is using the input in polling and see if that works, to nail down the problem that lies in the circuit or in the interrupt handler.

Comment: I believe your code is wrong.  Your interrupt is connected to EXTI2 although the vector for the handler is looking for EXTI0.  Change " EXTI0_IRQHandler" to " EXTI2_IRQHandler"
Let me know if this fixes it

Comment: Well spotted. That's very likely the error.

Comment: @ShannonStrutz Greeeaaaattttzz! absolutely you are right! I changed it and now it's working! put your answer because I want to select your answer and +1

Comment: @VladimirCravero Hey, Vladimir, What a funny problem! can you see? sometimes these types of problems trouble me! because that's really simple!

Comment: Problems are always simple, people usually pay more attention to more complicated tasks.

Comment: Posted :D  
I've pulled my hair out before for the same problem so I was just like, "Lets check on that first"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interrupt is connected to `EXTI2` although the vector for the handler is looking for `EXTI0`. Change `EXTI0_IRQHandler` to  `EXTI2_IRQHandler`